Mysql query returning only one result for set of query inputs in where clause but has result for each input when querying individually
I'm using the following mysql query to get the latest entries from 3 tables for the given input numbers as part of the result but the query returns result for only one of the numbers when passing as a set although each of these numbers have result when queried individually with the same query.
SELECT
    users.id,
    user_refs.is_active,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(user_bookings.id ), ',', 1) AS user_bookings_Id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(user_cancels.id ), ',', 1) AS user_cancels_Id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(user_stays.id ), ',', 1) AS user_stays_Id
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN 
    user_refs ON
    user_refs.user_id = users.id
left JOIN  user_bookings user_bookings on
    user_bookings.user_id = users.id
    and (user_bookings.user_bookings_status = 'RECEIVED'
        or user_bookings.user_bookings_status = 'PENDING'
        or user_bookings.user_bookings_status = 'COMPLETED')
    and user_bookings.is_active = 1
LEFT JOIN  user_cancels user_cancels on
    user_cancels.user_id = users.id
    and (user_cancels.status = 'RECEIVED'
        or user_cancels.status = 'PENDING'
        or user_cancels.status = 'COMPLETED'
        or user_cancels.status = 'REVIEWED'
        or user_cancels.status = 'OPEN')
LEFT JOIN  user_stays user_stays on
    user_stays.user_id = users.id
    and (user_stays.status = 'ONGOING'
        or user_stays.status = 'PENDING'
        or user_stays.status = 'COMPLETED')
WHERE
    users.contact_number IN ("95600014545", "6560001004", "7672356444");

Since I'm using left join not having data in one or more of the tables should not be the cause. I'm not sure why the query is returning only one result, is it because I'm using group concat in select?
The result I'm getting is the one which has entries in all 3 tables.

You should avoid these long, unhandy OR conditions and rather write user_cancels.status IN ('RECEIVED','PENDING','COMPLETED','REVIEWED','OPEN'). And why do you use double quotes for the numbers in your WHERE clause? If these numbers are really such, remove those quotes. If they are strings, just use single quotes as you did in your OR conditions above.

You use aggregate function (GROUP_CONCAT) without explicit GROUP BY, hence, implicit GROUP BY is performed, and the whole rowset is considered as one group which results in one output row.

Hey @JonasMetzler thanks for the review, the numbers are strings and the using IN instead of OR is actually a nice idea, it didn't occur to me

Thanks @Akina, this worked, could you please explain why the result is only one out of the 3 rows in case of implicit group by instead of the three rows in like maybe one row together?

?? What is not clear in my words implicit GROUP BY is performed, and the whole rowset is considered as one group which results in one output row? One group - one output row. And indefinite values in non-grouped output columns. Recommendation - enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in SQL Server Mode (study this term carefully!). With it your query will fail due to the incorrectness.

Yep, that is the problem. The query is invalid, but you are using MySQL in an old cheat mode that should not be used. In MySQL make sure to always be in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, so the DBMS tells you about the syntax error instead of muddling through and returning some arbitrary result. As is, you tell the DBMS to return one result row with the concatenated strings, but you also tell it to return the user ID and the active flag, but there is no the user ID and the active flag for the data - there are possibly several.

By the way: Why SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(user_bookings.id ), ',', 1)? You collect all booking IDs in arbitrary order and then pick the first one. You can just as well just use ANY_VALUE(user_bookings.id) (or MIN or MAX), which would be much more readable. In your description you say you take the "latest entries", but I don't see any ORDER BY in your query to sort the data in order to get the "latest".

I have an inkling that you want a quite different query, actually, but for this to know you would have to describe the tables and the complete task.

@ThorstenKettner, I just need to check if there is any value in the tables for that particular user for some validation, but to avoid having multiple rows in the resultset for the same user, I'm using substring_index with group_concat.
There can be multiple entries for the same user in user_bookings, user_stays and user_cancels tables but only one each in users and user_refs

If you just want to check whether there exists a user_stays row with status in ('ONGOING','PENDING','COMPLETED'), why do you select an ID? Doesn't it suffice to say yes, there exists such row or no, there does not exists such row?

I have enhanced your query with some improvements, which improves the readability.
SELECT
  u.id,
  ur.is_active,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( ub.id ), ',', 1 ) AS user_bookings_Id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( uc.id ), ',', 1 ) AS user_cancels_Id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( user_stays.id ), ',', 1 ) AS user_stays_Id 
FROM
  users u
LEFT JOIN 
  user_refs ur ON ur.user_id = u.id

LEFT JOIN 
  user_bookings ub ON ub.user_id = u.id AND ub.is_active = 1 
  -- Removed OR function and added IN function
  AND ub.user_bookings_status IN ('RECEIVED','PENDING','COMPLETED')

LEFT JOIN 
  user_cancels uc ON uc.user_id = u.id 
  AND uc.`STATUS` IN ('RECEIVED','PENDING','COMPLETED','REVIEWED','OPEN')

LEFT JOIN 
  user_stays user_stays ON user_stays.user_id = u.id 
  AND user_stays.`STATUS` IN ('ONGOING','PENDING','COMPLETED') 

WHERE
  -- Removed quotes If they are strings please use quotes
  u.contact_number IN (95600014545,6560001004,7672356444) 

 -- When using GROUP_CONCAT, ensure proper grouping to avoid retrieving only a single line of result.
GROUP BY
  u.id

